# Can gentoo provide a Xorg/Wayland + Browser , without needing dbus, udev and systemd?

Tags: systemd, udev, gentoo, d-bus

I have for the good part of a day tried to install gentoo distribution, desiring to avoid at all costs the following software

- dbus
- systemd
- udev

My assumption was that using the `USE` flags in `/etc/portage/make.conf` I could simply insert
USE=`-systemd -dbus -udev` to prevent the undesired software.

However it seems that in contrast to the `USE` flag, I have trouble to install any `graphical` `DE`, preferable `wayland` (even though, at the current point I would settle for `Xorg`).

My question, is what I have been attempting even possible? Can gentoo be setup to provide a `DE` without forcing me to use `dbus`?
If this was possible a answer hiting to a tutorial/resource the describes a way to accomplish this would be very much appreciated

Comment: It appears that [Gnome will always require systemd](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hard_dependencies_on_systemd), so you would need to chose software that does not have a hard dependency on `systemd`.  There is a [wiki article on using gnome with wayland without systemd](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GNOME/GNOME_Without_systemd) if that helps.  Also, the [Gentoo without systemd wiki article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Gentoo_Without_systemd) says you need to utilize the `USE` flags in addition to masking `systemd` and `udev`

Comment: @GracefulRestart thanks for the comment. In all honesty, I can do very well without the "*comfort*" of `Gnome` anyway. I seek to employ minima stuff in the philosophy of [suckless.org](https://suckless.org), [tinyWM](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17765446), or [Tiny Wayland Compositor] (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17773982). In essesnce all I need is to have a web browser running, anything else I can do on the command line -much prefereable to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

As a veteran Gentoo user, I'll provide this answer as a Work In Progress:

### Establish a Baseline

1. Select the baseline profile: `# eselect profile list && eselect profile set 1`, which should set the profile to: `[1]   default/linux/amd64/13.0 (stable)`
2. `# emerge -ea @system && emerge -ea @world`, which will build the System set, and then all the packages on your system with the default profile.  `udev` is required in this situation, because udev is now required by the kernel in all situations, but this will remove all reliance on `systemd` and use SysV as the default init system.

### Verify Compile Settings

1. Edit `/etc/portage/make.conf`. Set `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS` to your stable arch, most likely `x86` or `amd64`.
2. Install the Gentoo USE Flag Editor: `# emerge -av ufed`.
3. Start USE Flag Editor: `# ufed`.
4. Select the first option in the list: `-*`, which reads: `Never enable any flags other than those specified in make.conf`. This will now ignore the default flags set in Baseline Step 1.
5. Reissue Baseline Step 2: `# emerge -ea @system && emerge -ea @world`.  Portage  will now spit out the modifications required by the packages on your system.  Some of the required ones are `udev`, and `consolekit`.  Note that adding them using `ufed` is easier now because hitting spacebar multiple times will add the flag, then add a minus sign in front then remove the flag from the list.
6. If any package requires support for a flag you removed add it to `/etc/portage/package.use`.

### Resources

[Working With Portage Files](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Portage/Files)